# Half Square Symbols

Tags: symbols

I am looking for these symbols.

[image]

What package should I include?

Comment: A good thread to check first: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [`stix`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stix) package

```
\lrtriangle
\lrblacktriangle
```

Alternatively, you can use [`unicode-math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) with these commands:

```
\varlrtriangle
\lrblacktriangle
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw them:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3draw,amsmath,amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\whitetriangle}{}
 {
  \mathord{ \text { \sukan_triangle:n { stroke } } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\filledtriangle}{}
 {
  \mathord{ \text { \sukan_triangle:n { fill } } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sukan_triangle:n
 {
  \hspace{0.1em}
  \draw_begin:
  \draw_linewidth:n {0.1ex}
  \draw_join_round:
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.0em, 0.0em }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.7em, 0.0em }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.7em, 0.7em }
  \draw_path_close:
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { #1 }
  \draw_end:
  \hspace{0.1em}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This is an example $\whitetriangle+\filledtriangle+\square$

At reduced sizes $\scriptstyle\whitetriangle+\filledtriangle$
and $\scriptscriptstyle\whitetriangle+\filledtriangle$

\end{document}
```

[image]